# Tinymce in not working on android tablet 3.1

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-plugins, tinymce

I am developing an app in an android tablet using phonegap. Every thing working fine except tinymce plugin. Tinymce ui will display well. But unable to enter the text in rich text editor area.  And I don't know this plugin was support the android tablet or not. I am new to phonegap and app development. I am unable to find solution for this in net. Please help me to solve this problem.

Please suggest me any other plugin like tinymce is work well in android tablet.

Comment: Search for "html rich text editor" in your favorite search engine to find plenty of alternatives. SO isn't going to be able to help you choose, since there's no right answer to that question.